# Seg. Fault in Hash Table ADT - C

Tags: c, hash, adt

## Edit:

Hash.c is updated with revisions from the comments, I am still getting a Seg fault. I must be missing something here that you guys are saying

I have created a hash table ADT using C but I am encountering a segmentation fault when I try to call a function (find_hash) in the ADT.

I have posted all 3 files that I created parse.c, hash.c, and hash.h, so you can see all of the variables. We are reading from the file gettysburg.txt which is also attached

The seg fault is occuring in parse.c when I call find_hash. I cannot figure out for the life of me what is going on here. If you need anymore information I can surely provide it.

sorry for the long amount of code I have just been completely stumped for a week now on this. Thanks in advance

The way I run the program is first: 
      gcc -o parse parse.c hash.c
then: cat gettysburg.txt | parse

## Parse.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "hash.h"

#define WORD_SIZE 40
#define DICTIONARY_SIZE 1000

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0


void lower_case_word(char *);
void dump_dictionary(Phash_table ); 

/*Hash and compare functions*/
int hash_func(char *);
int cmp_func(void *, void *);

typedef struct user_data_ {   
    char word[WORD_SIZE];
    int freq_counter;
} user_data, *Puser_data;

int main(void)
{
   char c, word1[WORD_SIZE];
   int char_index = 0, dictionary_size = 0, num_words = 0, i;
   int total=0, largest=0;
   float average = 0.0;

   Phash_table t;                  //Pointer to main hash_table
   int (*Phash_func)(char *)=NULL;         //Function Pointers
   int (*Pcmp_func)(void *, void *)=NULL;
   Puser_data data_node;                   //pointer to hash table above
   user_data * find;


   printf("Parsing input ...\n");

   Phash_func = hash_func;   //Assigning Function pointers
   Pcmp_func = cmp_func;
   t = new_hash(1000,Phash_func,Pcmp_func);

  // Read in characters until end is reached 
  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if ((c == ' ') || (c == ',') || (c == '.') || (c == '!') || (c == '"') ||
        (c == ':') || (c == '\n')) {
          // End of a word 
      if (char_index) {
          // Word is not empty 
        word1[char_index] = '\0';
        lower_case_word(word1);

        data_node = (Puser_data)malloc(sizeof(user_data));  
        strcpy(data_node->word,word1);
        printf("%s\n", data_node->word);


    //!!!!!!SEG FAULT HERE!!!!!!

        if (!((user_data *)find_hash(t, data_node->word))){   //SEG FAULT!!!!
         insert_hash(t,word1,(void *)data_node); 
        }

        char_index = 0;
        num_words++;
      }
    } else {
      // Continue assembling word 
      word1[char_index++] = c;
    }
  }

  printf("There were %d words; %d unique words.\n", num_words,
     dictionary_size);
  dump_dictionary(t);  //???

  }

void lower_case_word(char *w){
  int i = 0;

  while (w[i] != '\0') {
    w[i] = tolower(w[i]);
    i++;
  }
}

void dump_dictionary(Phash_table t){  //???
  int i;
  user_data *cur, *cur2;

  stat_hash(t, &(t->total), &(t->largest), &(t->average));   //Call to stat hash
    printf("Number of unique words:  %d\n", t->total);
    printf("Largest Bucket:  %d\n", t->largest);
    printf("Average Bucket:  %f\n", t->average);  

  cur = start_hash_walk(t);
  printf("%s:  %d\n", cur->word, cur->freq_counter);

  for (i = 0; i < t->total; i++)
     cur2 = next_hash_walk(t);
     printf("%s:  %d\n", cur2->word, cur2->freq_counter);
}

int hash_func(char *string){
    int i, sum=0, temp, index;

    for(i=0; i < strlen(string);i++){
        sum += (int)string[i];  
    }
    index = sum % 1000;
return (index); 
}


/*array1 and array2 point to the user defined data struct defined above*/
int cmp_func(void *array1, void *array2){

user_data *cur1= array1;
user_data *cur2= array2;//(user_data *)array2;

    if(cur1->freq_counter < cur2->freq_counter){
        return(-1);}
        else{ if(cur1->freq_counter > cur2->freq_counter){
                return(1);}
                else return(0);}
}
```

## hash.c

```
#include "hash.h"

Phash_table new_hash (int size, int(*hash_func)(char*), int(*cmp_func)(void*, void*)){
    int i;
    Phash_table t;

    t = (Phash_table)malloc(sizeof(hash_table));   //creates the main hash table
    t->buckets = (hash_entry **)malloc(sizeof(hash_entry *)*size);  //creates the hash table of "size" buckets
    t->size = size;   //Holds the number of buckets
    t->hash_func = hash_func;   //assigning the pointer to the function in the user's program
    t->cmp_func = cmp_func;     // "  "  
    t->total=0;
    t->largest=0;
    t->average=0;
    t->sorted_array = NULL;
    t->index=0;
    t->sort_num=0;

    for(i=0;i<size;i++){   //Sets all buckets in hash table to NULL
        t->buckets[i] = NULL;}

    return(t);
}

void free_hash(Phash_table table){
    int i;
    hash_entry *cur;

    for(i = 0; i<(table->size);i++){
        if(table->buckets[i] != NULL){
            for(cur=table->buckets[i]; cur->next != NULL; cur=cur->next){
                free(cur->key);  //Freeing memory for key and data
                free(cur->data);
            }
      free(table->buckets[i]);    //free the whole bucket
    }}
    free(table->sorted_array);
    free(table);
}

void insert_hash(Phash_table table, char *key, void *data){
    Phash_entry new_node;   //pointer to a new node of type hash_entry
    int index;

    new_node = (Phash_entry)malloc(sizeof(hash_entry));
    new_node->key = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(key)+1)); //creates the key array based on the length of the string-based key
    new_node->data = data;       //stores the user's data into the node
    strcpy(new_node->key,key);   //copies the key into the node

                                //calling the hash function in the user's program
    index = table->hash_func(key);    //index will hold the hash table value for where the new node will be placed
    table->buckets[index] = new_node; //Assigns the pointer at the index value to the new node
    table->total++;   //increment the total (total # of buckets)
}

void *find_hash(Phash_table table, char *key){
    int i;
    hash_entry *cur;
   printf("Inside find_hash\n"); //REMOVE

    for(i = 0;i<table->size;i++){
        if(table->buckets[i]!=NULL){            
            for(cur = table->buckets[i]; cur->next != NULL; cur = cur->next){
                if(strcmp(table->buckets[i]->key, key) == 0)
                return((table->buckets[i]->data));}  //returns the data to the user if the key values match
        }    //otherwise return NULL, if no match was found.
    }   
    return NULL;
}
void stat_hash(Phash_table table, int *total, int *largest, float *average){

    int node_num[table->size];  //creates an array, same size as table->size(# of buckets)
    int i,j, count = 0;
    int largest_buck = 0;
    hash_entry *cur;

    for(i = 0; i < table->size; i ++){
        if(table->buckets[i] != NULL){
            for(cur=table->buckets[i]; cur->next!=NULL; cur = cur->next){
                count ++;}
            node_num[i] = count;
            count = 0;}
        }

    for(j = 0; j < table->size; j ++){      
        if(node_num[j] > largest_buck)
            largest_buck = node_num[j];}

    *total = table->total;
    *largest = largest_buck;
    *average = (table->total) / (table->size);
}

void *start_hash_walk(Phash_table table){
    Phash_table temp = table;
    int i, j, k;
    hash_entry *cur;  //CHANGE IF NEEDED to HASH_TABLE *

    if(table->sorted_array != NULL) free(table->sorted_array);

    table->sorted_array = (void**)malloc(sizeof(void*)*(table->total));

    for(i = 0; i < table->total; i++){
        if(table->buckets[i]!=NULL){
            for(cur=table->buckets[i]; cur->next != NULL; cur=cur->next){
                table->sorted_array[i] = table->buckets[i]->data;
        }}
    }

    for(j = (table->total) - 1; j > 0; j --)    {
        for(k = 1; k <= j; k ++){
            if(table->cmp_func(table->sorted_array[k-1], table->sorted_array[k]) == 1){
                temp -> buckets[0]-> data = table->sorted_array[k-1];
                table->sorted_array[k-1] = table->sorted_array[k];
                table->sorted_array[k] = temp->buckets[0] -> data;
            }
        }
    }
    return table->sorted_array[table->sort_num];
}

void *next_hash_walk(Phash_table table){ 

    table->sort_num ++;
    return table->sorted_array[table->sort_num];
}
```

## hash.h

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct hash_entry_ {    //Linked List
    void *data;                 //Generic pointer
    char *key;                  //String-based key value
    struct hash_entry_ *next;   //Self-Referencing pointer
} hash_entry, *Phash_entry;

typedef struct hash_table_ {
    hash_entry **buckets;           //Pointer to a pointer to a Linked List of type hash_entry
    int (*hash_func)(char *);
    int (*cmp_func)(void *, void *);
    int size;
    void **sorted_array;         //Array used to sort each hash entry
    int index;
    int total;
    int largest;
    float average;  
    int sort_num;
} hash_table, *Phash_table;


Phash_table new_hash(int size, int (*hash_func)(char *), int (*cmp_func)(void *, void *));
void free_hash(Phash_table table);
void insert_hash(Phash_table table, char *key, void *data);
void *find_hash(Phash_table table, char *key);
void stat_hash(Phash_table table, int *total, int *largest, float *average);
void *start_hash_walk(Phash_table table);
void *next_hash_walk(Phash_table table);
```

## Gettysburg.txt

```
Four score and seven years ago, our fathers brought forth upon this continent a new nation: conceived in liberty, and dedicated to the proposition that all men are created equal.

Now we are engaged in a great civil war. . .testing whether that nation, or any nation so conceived and so dedicated. . . can long endure. We are met on a great battlefield of that war.

We have come to dedicate a portion of that field as a final resting place for those who here gave their lives that that nation might live. It is altogether fitting and proper that we should do this.

But, in a larger sense, we cannot dedicate. . .we cannot consecrate. . . we cannot hallow this ground. The brave men, living and dead, who struggled here have consecrated it, far above our poor power to add or detract. The world will little note, nor long remember, what we say here, but it can never forget what they did here.

It is for us the living, rather, to be dedicated here to the unfinished work which they who fought here have thus far so nobly advanced. It is rather for us to be here dedicated to the great task remaining before us. . .that from these honored dead we take increased devotion to that cause for which they gave the last full measure of devotion. . . that we here highly resolve that these dead shall not have died in vain. . . that this nation, under God, shall have a new birth of freedom. . . and that government of the people. . .by the people. . .for the people. . . shall not perish from the earth.
```

Comment: strcpy(new->key,key); - I don't think that line compiles, at least when I try it it doesn't.

Comment: It didn't compile because its supposed to say strcpy(new_node->key,key)...sorry I have it changed in my source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm,

here's hash.c

```
#include "hash.h"

Phash_table new_hash (int size, int(*hash_func)(char*), int(*cmp_func)(void*, void*)){
    int i;
    Phash_table t;

    t = (Phash_table)calloc(1, sizeof(hash_table));   //creates the main hash table
    t->buckets = (hash_entry **)calloc(size, sizeof(hash_entry *));  //creates the hash table of "size" buckets
    t->size = size;   //Holds the number of buckets
    t->hash_func = hash_func;   //assigning the pointer to the function in the user's program
    t->cmp_func = cmp_func;     // "  "  
    t->total=0;
    t->largest=0;
    t->average=0;

    for(i=0;t->buckets[i] != NULL;i++){   //Sets all buckets in hash table to NULL
        t->buckets[i] = NULL;}

    return(t);
}

void free_hash(Phash_table table){
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i<(table->size);i++){
        if(table->buckets[i]!=NULL)
            for(table->buckets[i]; table->buckets[i]->next != NULL; table->buckets[i] = table->buckets[i]->next){
                free(table->buckets[i]->key);  //Freeing memory for key and data
                free(table->buckets[i]->data);
            }
      free(table->buckets[i]);    //free the whole bucket
    }
    free(table->sorted_array);
    free(table);
}

void insert_hash(Phash_table table, char *key, void *data){
    Phash_entry new_node;   //pointer to a new node of type hash_entry
    int index;

    new_node = (Phash_entry)calloc(1,sizeof(hash_entry));
    new_node->key = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(key)+1)); //creates the key array based on the length of the string-based key
    new_node->data = data;       //stores the user's data into the node
    strcpy(new_node->key,key);   //copies the key into the node

                                //calling the hash function in the user's program
    index = table->hash_func(key);    //index will hold the hash table value for where the new node will be placed
    table->buckets[index] = new_node; //Assigns the pointer at the index value to the new node
    table->total++;   //increment the total (total # of buckets)
}

void *find_hash(Phash_table table, char *key){
    int i;
hash_entry *cur;

   printf("Inside find_hash\n"); //REMOVE

    for(i = 0;i<table->size;i++){
        if(table->buckets[i]!=NULL){
            for (cur = table->buckets[i]; cur != NULL; cur = cur->next){
            //for(table->buckets[i]; table->buckets[i]->next != NULL; table->buckets[i] = table->buckets[i]->next){
                if(strcmp(cur->key, key) == 0)
                   return((cur->data));}  //returns the data to the user if the key values match
        }    //otherwise return NULL, if no match was found.
    }   
    return NULL;
}
void stat_hash(Phash_table table, int *total, int *largest, float *average){

    int node_num[table->size];    
    int i,j, count = 0;
    int largest_buck = 0;
    hash_entry *cur;

    for(i = 0; i < table->size; i ++)
    {
        if(table->buckets[i]!=NULL)            
            for (cur = table->buckets[i]; cur != NULL; cur = cur->next){
            //for(table->buckets[i]; table->buckets[i]->next != NULL; table->buckets[i] = table->buckets[i]->next){
                count ++;}

        node_num[i] = count;
        count = 0;
    }

    for(j = 0; j < table->size; j ++){
        if(node_num[j] > largest_buck)
            largest_buck = node_num[j];}

    *total = table->total;
    *largest = largest_buck;
    *average = (table->total) /(float) (table->size); //oook: i think you want a fp average
}

void *start_hash_walk(Phash_table table){
    void* temp = 0; //oook: this was another way of overwriting your input table 
    int i, j, k; 
    int l=0; //oook: new counter for elements in your sorted_array
    hash_entry *cur;

    if(table->sorted_array !=NULL) free(table->sorted_array);

    table->sorted_array = (void**)calloc((table->total), sizeof(void*));

    for(i = 0; i < table->size; i ++){
    //for(i = 0; i < table->total; i++){  //oook: i don't think you meant total ;)
        if(table->buckets[i]!=NULL)
            for (cur = table->buckets[i]; cur != NULL; cur = cur->next){
            //for(table->buckets[i]; table->buckets[i]->next != NULL; table->buckets[i] = table->buckets[i]->next){
                table->sorted_array[l++] = cur->data;
            }
    }

    //oook: sanity check/assert on expected values
    if (l != table->total)
    {
        printf("oook: l[%d] != table->total[%d]\n",l,table->total);
    }

    for(j = (l) - 1; j > 0; j --)    {
        for(k = 1; k <= j; k ++){
            if (table->sorted_array[k-1] && table->sorted_array[k])
            {
                if(table->cmp_func(table->sorted_array[k-1], table->sorted_array[k]) == 1){
                    temp = table->sorted_array[k-1]; //ook. changed temp to void* see assignment
                    table->sorted_array[k-1] = table->sorted_array[k];
                    table->sorted_array[k] = temp;
                }
            }
            else
                printf("if (table->sorted_array[k-1] && table->sorted_array[k])\n");
        }
    }
    return table->sorted_array[table->sort_num];
}

void *next_hash_walk(Phash_table table){ 

    /*oook: this was blowing up since you were incrementing past the size of sorted_array..
    NB: *you **need** to implement some bounds checking here or you will endup with more seg-faults!!*/
    //table->sort_num++
    return table->sorted_array[table->sort_num++];
}
```

here's parse.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>  //oook: added so you can assert ;)
#include "hash.h"

#define WORD_SIZE 40
#define DICTIONARY_SIZE 1000

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0


void lower_case_word(char *);
void dump_dictionary(Phash_table ); 

/*Hash and compare functions*/
int hash_func(char *);
int cmp_func(void *, void *);

typedef struct user_data_ {   
    char word[WORD_SIZE];
    int freq_counter;
} user_data, *Puser_data;

int main(void)
{
   char c, word1[WORD_SIZE];
   int char_index = 0, dictionary_size = 0, num_words = 0, i;
   int total=0, largest=0;
   float average = 0.0;

   Phash_table t;                  //Pointer to main hash_table
   int (*Phash_func)(char *)=NULL;         //Function Pointers
   int (*Pcmp_func)(void *, void *)=NULL;
   Puser_data data_node;                   //pointer to hash table above
   user_data * find;


   printf("Parsing input ...\n");

   Phash_func = hash_func;   //Assigning Function pointers
   Pcmp_func = cmp_func;
   t = new_hash(1000,Phash_func,Pcmp_func);

  // Read in characters until end is reached 
  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if ((c == ' ') || (c == ',') || (c == '.') || (c == '!') || (c == '"') ||
        (c == ':') || (c == '\n')) {
          // End of a word 
      if (char_index) {
          // Word is not empty 
        word1[char_index] = '\0';
        lower_case_word(word1);

        data_node = (Puser_data)calloc(1,sizeof(user_data));  
        strcpy(data_node->word,word1);
        printf("%s\n", data_node->word);


    //!!!!!!SEG FAULT HERE!!!!!!

        if (!((user_data *)find_hash(t, data_node->word))){   //SEG FAULT!!!!
        dictionary_size++;
         insert_hash(t,word1,(void *)data_node); 
        }

        char_index = 0;
        num_words++;
      }
    } else {
      // Continue assembling word 
      word1[char_index++] = c;
    }
  }

  printf("There were %d words; %d unique words.\n", num_words,
     dictionary_size);
  dump_dictionary(t);  //???

  }

void lower_case_word(char *w){
  int i = 0;

  while (w[i] != '\0') {
    w[i] = tolower(w[i]);
    i++;
  }
}

void dump_dictionary(Phash_table t){  //???
  int i;
  user_data *cur, *cur2;

  stat_hash(t, &(t->total), &(t->largest), &(t->average));   //Call to stat hash
    printf("Number of unique words:  %d\n", t->total);
    printf("Largest Bucket:  %d\n", t->largest);
    printf("Average Bucket:  %f\n", t->average);  

  cur = start_hash_walk(t);
  if (!cur) //ook: do test or assert for null values
  {
    printf("oook: null== (cur = start_hash_walk)\n");
    exit(-1);
  }
  printf("%s:  %d\n", cur->word, cur->freq_counter);
  for (i = 0; i < t->total; i++)
  {//oook: i think you needed these braces
      cur2 = next_hash_walk(t);
      if (!cur2) //ook: do test or assert for null values
      {
        printf("oook: null== (cur2 = next_hash_walk(t) at i[%d])\n",i);
      }
      else
        printf("%s:  %d\n", cur2->word, cur2->freq_counter);
  }//oook: i think you needed these braces
}

int hash_func(char *string){
    int i, sum=0, temp, index;

    for(i=0; i < strlen(string);i++){
        sum += (int)string[i];  
    }
    index = sum % 1000;
return (index); 
}


/*array1 and array2 point to the user defined data struct defined above*/
int cmp_func(void *array1, void *array2){

user_data *cur1= array1;
user_data *cur2= array2;//(user_data *)array2;

    /* ooook: do assert on programmatic errors. 
    this function *requires non-null inputs.  */
    assert(cur1 && cur2);  
    if(cur1->freq_counter < cur2->freq_counter){
        return(-1);}
        else{ if(cur1->freq_counter > cur2->freq_counter){
                return(1);}
                else return(0);}
}
```

follow the `//ooks`

**Explanation:**
There were one or two places this was going to blow up in.
The quick fix and answer to your question was in `parse.c`, circa *L100*:

```
  cur = start_hash_walk(t);
  printf("%s:  %d\n", cur->word, cur->freq_counter);
```

..checking that `cur` is not `null` before calling `printf` fixes your immediate seg-fault.

But why would `cur` be `null` ? ~because of this bad-boy: 

`void *start_hash_walk(Phash_table table)`

Your `hash_func(char *string)` can (& does) return non-unique values. This is of course ok except that you have not yet implemented your linked list chains. Hence you end up with `table->sorted_array` containing less than `table->total` elements ~or you would if you were iterating over all `table->size` buckets ;)

There are one or two other issues.
For now i hacked [Nate Kohl's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/98654/nate-kohl) `for(cur=table->buckets[i]; cur->next != NULL; cur=cur->next)` further, to be `for(cur=table->buckets[i]; cur != NULL; cur=cur->next)` since you have no chains. But this is *your TODO so enough said about that.

Finally. note that in `next_hash_walk(Phash_table table)` you have:

```
table->sort_num++
return table->sorted_array[table->sort_num];
```

Ouch! *Do* check those array bounds!

**Notes**
1) If you're function isn't designed to change input, then make the input `const`. That way the compiler may well tell you when you're inadvertently trashing something.

2) Do bound checking on your array indices.

3) Do test/assert for Null pointers before attempting to use them.

4) Do unit test each of your functions; never write too much code before compiling & testing.

5) Use minimal test-data; craft it such that it limit-tests your code & attempts to break it in cunning ways.

6) Do initialise you data structures!

7)*Never use egyptian braces !* {
only joking ;)
 
}

**PS** *Good job so far ~> pointers are tricky little things! & a well asked question with all the necessary details so +1 and gl ;)*

(//oook: maybe add a *homework* tag)

Comment: Wow thank you very much, it doesnt seem like there were too many fixes, but they were crucial.

Comment: the program runs through now, however its now crashing at the dump_dictionary function. I will have to see what is going on there but it seems like hash.c is fixed. Thank you so much

Comment: it says unknown paste copy when i click the url

Comment: I see! the start_hash_walk function was pretty tricky. I have a sample output for the program if needed

Comment: i have a sample output of what the program should output for the txt file

Comment: cool. but did you get the code i posted to run yet? tell me you did so i can go to bed without worrying about you lol

Comment: Got it to run! thank you so much!! finally got passed that seg fault. I cant thank you enough, you have helped tremendously!!

Comment: nOP -i hope you get why it was seg-faulting now -must sleep will finish off explanation on my answer tomoz -tootle-pip ;)

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that one of several problems with this code are loops like:

```
for(table->buckets[i]; 
    table->buckets[i]->next != NULL; 
    table->buckets[i] = table->buckets[i]->next)
  ...
```

The initializing part of the for loop (`table->buckets[i]`) has no effect.  If `i` is 0 and `table->buckets[0] == NULL`, then the condition on this loop (`table->buckets[i]->next != NULL`) will dereference a null pointer and crash.

That's where your code seemed to be crashing for on my box, at least.  When I changed several of your loops to:

```
if (table->buckets[i] != NULL) {
  for(; 
      table->buckets[i]->next != NULL; 
      table->buckets[i] = table->buckets[i]->next)
    ...
}
```

...it kept crashing, but in a different place.  Maybe that will help get you unstuck?

---

**Edit**: another potential problem is that those for loops are destructive.  When you call `find_hash`, do you really want all of those buckets to be modified?

I'd suggest using something like:

```
hash_entry *cur;
// ...
if (table->buckets[i] != NULL) {
  for (cur = table->buckets[i]; cur->next != NULL; cur = cur->next) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

When I do that and comment out your `dump_dictionary` function, your code runs without crashing.

Comment: I wouldn't think that it would de-reference the NULL pointer since we have the check(if table->buckets[i]!=NULL) before the loop. So if the bucket is NULL it will not go inside to the loop

Comment: I do think the error is around there though. Would the printf inside the function find_hash still not print. I would have thought that once the function was called it would print "Inside find_hash" then crash.

Comment: @Toucan Sam: you don't have that NULL check everywhere, though: it's missing in free_hash, stat_hash, start_hash_walk...

Comment: oh I see so you I should include those in those functions as well. Do you think the program would crash even though those functions have yet to be called. I guess I can include those checks and then try and see. Thanks

Comment: @ToucanSam: another potential problem is destructive for loops -- see my last edit.

Comment: @ToucanSam prefer calloc to malloc, at glance i think you have some uninitialised data stuctures.. that said you're probably indexing an out-of-bounds array somewhere.. gl

Comment: I see what you mean. the code you posted is much better. would you reccommend to change the way a walk through the buckets in the other functions to the same way you have posted?

Comment: instead of hash_entry *cur would the code instead need to be hash_table *cur, since table->buckets[] is in the hash_table struct

Comment: @ToucanSam: yup.  I think all of the for loops you posted that involve `table->buckets[i]` should probably be changed.

Comment: Okay thanks. I modified the code for hash.c and posted it with the correct fixes but I am still getting the seg fault. I see you mentioned that you got it to run with no error, I am not sure where I am going wrong. I cant thank you enough for the help